# Switch between different views using href

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

I'm coming here after some head banging. Still learning php/mysql and coming across an issue which is bothering me for a while.

Currently I print a table with all the data without any condition. The values below the `lower`  values and above are printed in this table. The snippet of my code is below:

```
  while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" .$result['id']. "</td>";
       if ($result['time'] > $limit[lower]){

            echo "<td bgcolor=#ff0000>" $result['time']. "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>" .$result['time']. "</td>";
        }
            echo "<td>" .$result['name']. "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
    }
```

I want to create a href link so that by dafault only values above the `lower` are printed and on clicking the link, say `detailed_view` will give the table as it does above i.e. all value including below and above the `lower` value. Shall I create two methods and use them in href separately. In that case there will be two while loops which I want to avoid. Any pointer on this?

The name of the script is `display.php`, so before the loop I tried using:

```
     echo "<a href='display_jobid.php?view=$num'>Show All</a>";
```

It does create a hyperlink `Show All` but how to get the functionality working, am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn about querystrings http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php `<a href="mypage.php?lower=123">From 123</a>` and in PHP `$lower = $_GET['lower'];` which you use in your database where clause (after making it safe) `$sql.= 'WHERE something >= '.(int)$lower;` for example.

Comment: @Mehedi: Dont intend to use ajax currently.